# Sidekiq ignores I18n.locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

We have `I18n.locale` and `I18n.default_locale` set in our app (set in config/environments). Sidekiq seems to ignore `I18n.locale`  and uses `I18n.default_locale` for its workers. Requiring `'sidekiq/middleware/i18n'` in initializer doesn't change anything. Byebugging into worker, I get `I18n.locale` value equal to what is set as `I18n.default_locale` in environment settings. Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem?

We are not using ActiveJob.

Comment: you have to set `I18n.locale` before perform a worker.

Comment: @LamPhan it's set in config/environments. So it should be set at application startup, right?

Comment: if you already set `I18n.locale` which locale you want then i guess you maybe need to restart the sidekiq server.

Comment: It was restarted every time. That's some strange behaviour we don't understand.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/main/lib/sidekiq/middleware/i18n.rb#L12-L23) is how sidekiq I18n middle work, you could copy all (instead of requiring `'sidekiq/middleware/i18n'`) in order to debug `I18n.locale`on both sidekiq client and server.